# Expand a range of numbers with grep

Tags: shell, grep

I work in telecoms and regularly need to expand number ranges.

For example, `6121234567X`  [note that there are 10 numbers preceeding the X] is shorthand for:

```
61212345670
61212345671
61212345672....... etc (a 10 number range)
```

and `612123456X`  [note that there are only 9 numbers preceeding the X] is shorthand for

```
61212345600
61212345601....... etc (a 100 number range)
```

So I need a grep command that...

- reads how many characters in the line preceeding the X (to determine how many suffixes)
- writes the appropriate amount of lines (10, 100, or 100) with ascending suffixes
- hopefully removes the original line

Comment: Does this question perhaps belong to the Unix/Linux stack exchange site?

Comment: What you need is file editing/modification tool, in Linux `sed`, `awk` or even `perl`/`python` are usually used for that purpose...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `awk` quite quickly:

```
awk -v val=$a -v max=10
    'BEGIN {
            gsub("X","",val)
            items=max - length(val)
            for (i=0; i<=10^items; i++)
                print val*(10^items)+i
           }'
```

This works as an example. To do the same reading from a file, you just need to play with `$1` (first field of the field) instead of `val` and move all the code from `BEGIN` into the main block.

#### Explanation

- `-v val=$a -v max=10` pass parameters: `$a` is the variable containing the string on the form `12345678X` AND `max` contains the maximum amount of digits the number will have (10 in your case).
- `BEGIN {}` perform all these actions [before/without] reading a file.
- `gsub("X","",val)` remove `X` from `val`.
- `items=max - length(val)` count the size of the variable without the `X`.
- `for (i=0; i<=10^items; i++) print val*(10^items)+i` loop from `0` to 10^remaining_size. This means from 0 to 10 or from 0 to 100... depending on the result of 10 - size without X.

#### Test

With 9 as maximum:

```
$ a=12345678X
$ awk -v val=$a -v max=9 'BEGIN {gsub("X","",val); items=max - length(val); for (i=0; i<=10^items; i++) print val*(10^items)+i}'
123456780
123456781
123456782
123456783
123456784
123456785
123456786
123456787
123456788
123456789
123456790
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Python script that does it, file-name is the expected first argument. Example usage: `python script.py file.in > file.out`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def generate(pattern):
    p = pattern.lower().find('x')
    ret = ""
    for i in range(10**(10-p+1)):
        ret += pattern[:p] + str(i).zfill(10-p+1) + " "
    return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print("Filename needed!")
    else:
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
            for ln in f:
                print(generate(ln.rstrip()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo 6121234567X |    perl -nE 'm/(.*)X/;  
       say $1. $_ foreach (0..10**(11-length $1)-1)'
    61212345670
    61212345671
    61212345672
    61212345673
    61212345674
    61212345675
    61212345676
    61212345677
    61212345678
    61212345679
```

It's a little uglier to get the zero padded format:

```
echo 611234567X |  perl -wne 'm/(.*)X/; $b=$1; $r=11 - length $b;  
     $fmt="%0" . $r . "s\n";
     printf "$b$fmt", $_ foreach (0..10**$r-1) '
```